# Understanding this query (COUNT & subquery)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble understanding this query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `advertise` parent 
 WHERE 3  <= ( SELECT COUNT(username) 
                 FROM `advertise` 
                WHERE keyword = parent.keyword 
                  AND bid > parent.bid) 
   AND username = 'mike'
```

What this query does is display any rows with the username `'mike'`; if that row is not in the three highest bids for a keyword.

Here is the [sqlfiddle that works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42223/1), but I don't understand how it works.  More specifically I don't understand `3 <=` with this specific query.

How does `3 <=` determine the row is not in the three highest bids for a keyword?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(...) returns an integer

Comment: Change the 3 to a 4 in your SQL fiddle. Does that help?

Comment: that still doesn't explain how it determines the row isn't in the three highest results.  That means the query would look something like this once returned  SELECT * 
  FROM `advertise` parent 
 WHERE 3  <= 2 AND username = 'mike'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query works like so:

The subquery

```
SELECT COUNT(username) FROM `advertise` WHERE keyword = parent.keyword AND bid > parent.bid
```

finds the number of rows that have a higher bid for the same keyword. We then specify that the bid we are looking for cannot be in the top three bids, so we require that at least 3 bids be returned from that query. Here is what I think your end query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `advertise` parent 
WHERE 3  <= ( SELECT COUNT(username) 
    FROM `advertise` 
    WHERE keyword = parent.keyword 
    AND bid > parent.bid) 
AND username = 'mike'
```

Comment: why do you use at least 4 bids?

Comment: I've updated it to 3. I had to rethink it, but I believe 3 is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can be made a bit simpler to read if it's reformatted slightly:

```
SELECT * FROM `advertise` parent 

WHERE (SELECT COUNT(username) 
   FROM `advertise` 
   WHERE keyword=parent.keyword 
   AND bid>parent.bid) >= 3 

AND username='mike'
```

The sub query is evaluated for each line returned from the parent query so it will be doing `X >= 3` for each line.